# In excel pivot: How can I how count as percentage of row total, but row total as value?

Tags: excel, pivot-table

In a pivot table, I can show a row as

```
label1 | 1100 | 500 | 200 | 200 | 2000
```

or

```
label1 | 55% | 25% | 10% | 10% | 100%
```

By using 'Show Value As' '% of Row Total' in 'Value Field Settings'

But I would like:

```
label1 | 55% | 25% | 10% | 10% | 2000
```

Is that possible?

Even better would be:

```
label1 | 1100 (55%) | 500 (25%) | 200 (10%) | 200 (10%) | 2000 (100%)
```

I know I can have the latter by dragging the same field to the Values area twice, but this results in two columns per value which is confusing

Comment: Use a formula that concatenates the value and percent into a single string.

Comment: @FDavidov: can you elaborage?

Comment: Something like: `CONCATENATE(<your_value>," ",(100*<your_value>/<Total>,"%")`.

Comment: what is '<your_value>'? where do i do this in a pivot table?

Comment: `'<your_value>'` would be the reference to the cells holding the values 1100,500,...

Comment: I guess that from the above you understand what `<Total>` stands for.

Comment: we're talking about a pivot table, not a regular one.

Comment: You could define cells (e.g. a column) next to the one hosting the VALUE which would hold the formula, and use that column for the pivot. Still, if this is not what you are looking for, I'm out of ideas. Sorry.